# certbot version updgrade not implemented

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, apache2, letsencrypt

I want to update `certbot` to cope with following topic: 
[How to stop using TLS-SNI-01 with Certbot](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-stop-using-tls-sni-01-with-certbot/83210)

Before updgrade: `certbot --version` returns: `certbot 0.26.1`

As instructed in [How to stop using TLS-SNI-01 with Certbot](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-stop-using-tls-sni-01-with-certbot/83210), I want to update to a version above 0.28.

I've looked how to upgrade on `ubuntu` I've executed:

`apt-get install –only-upgrade python-certbot-apache`

It returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-opcache
  php7.0-readline python-acme python-augeas python-certbot python-cffi-backend
  python-chardet python-configargparse python-configobj python-cryptography
  python-dialog python-dnspython python-enum34 python-funcsigs python-idna
  python-ipaddress python-mock python-ndg-httpsclient python-openssl
  python-parsedatetime python-pbr python-pyasn1 python-requests python-rfc3339
  python-six python-tz python-urllib3 python-zope.component python-zope.event
  python-zope.hookable python-zope.interface
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python-certbot-apache
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 270 not upgraded.
Need to get 3872 B of archives.
After this operation, 3072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python-certbot-apache all 0.28.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3 [3872 B]
Fetched 3872 B in 0s (28.3 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 38437 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-certbot-apache_0.28.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-certbot-apache (0.28.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3) over (0.25.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1) ...
Setting up python-certbot-apache (0.28.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3) ...
```

So it looks like the update was successful.

Also when I do `certbot --version` it still returns: `certbot 0.26.1`

Comment: You have 270 not upgraded packages, is it possible there are some dependencies. If you need to keep the current version of some package use `sudo apt-mark hold package-name` and upgrade the rest. On my server `certbot` was upgraded without any issues.

Comment: Thanks for the clue @pa4080, I've updated packages `python3-certbot` and `python3-certbot-apache`. `certbot --version` returns `certbot 0.28.0` now. Please post your answer, so I can mark it as resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to upgrade certbot on Ubuntu Bionic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113499/failed-to-upgrade-certbot-on-ubuntu-bionic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 270 not upgraded packages, it is possible there are some dependencies. If you need to keep the current version of some package use `sudo apt-mark hold package-name` and upgrade the rest. Or find the dependencies that should be upgraded.

On my server `certbot` was upgraded without any issues, when I've used just `sudo apt upgrade`.

---

Based on the OP's report, the concrete answer of the question is both packages `python3-certbot` and `python3-certbot-apache` must be upgraded.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you just use sudo apt-get upgrade it will not find the new package.

Here are the full steps I used with Ubuntu 16 to upgrade certbot from 0.26 to 0.28:

1.) check certbot version. If lower that 0.28 it need to be updated.

```
certbot --version || /path/to/certbot-auto --version
```

2.) Run these commands to update certbot

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

3.) disable tls-sni-01 for certbot

```
sudo sh -c "sed -i.bak -e 's/^\(pref_challs.*\)tls-sni-01\(.*\)/\1http-01\2/g' /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*; rm -f /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.bak"
```

4.) re run certbot:

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```